# Can PreparedStatement's 'setObject' method be used for any datatype?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Can the `PreparedStatement`'s `.setObject` method be used for any data type (`String`, `Integer`, `Double`, `Date`, `DateTime`, `Byte Array`, etc.) supported by MySQL instead of using the individual `.setInt`, `.setDouble`, etc. methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. But It's depends on JDBC Driver.
If you pass Int Value, setObject convert to setInt() method

Passed Object is analyzed by JDBC Driver's PreparedStatement Implementation class.

Mysql JDBC Connector's Code snippet

```
public void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object parameterObj) throws SQLException {
    synchronized (checkClosed().getConnectionMutex()) {
        if (parameterObj == null) {
            setNull(parameterIndex, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
        } else {
            if (parameterObj instanceof Byte) {
                setInt(parameterIndex, ((Byte) parameterObj).intValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof String) {
                setString(parameterIndex, (String) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof BigDecimal) {
                setBigDecimal(parameterIndex, (BigDecimal) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Short) {
                setShort(parameterIndex, ((Short) parameterObj).shortValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Integer) {
                setInt(parameterIndex, ((Integer) parameterObj).intValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Long) {
                setLong(parameterIndex, ((Long) parameterObj).longValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Float) {
                setFloat(parameterIndex, ((Float) parameterObj).floatValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Double) {
                setDouble(parameterIndex, ((Double) parameterObj).doubleValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof byte[]) {
                setBytes(parameterIndex, (byte[]) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Date) {
                setDate(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Date) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Time) {
                setTime(parameterIndex, (Time) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Timestamp) {
                setTimestamp(parameterIndex, (Timestamp) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof Boolean) {
                setBoolean(parameterIndex, ((Boolean) parameterObj).booleanValue());
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof InputStream) {
                setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, (InputStream) parameterObj, -1);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Blob) {
                setBlob(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Blob) parameterObj);
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Clob) {
                setClob(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Clob) parameterObj);
            } else if (this.connection.getTreatUtilDateAsTimestamp() && parameterObj instanceof java.util.Date) {
                setTimestamp(parameterIndex, new Timestamp(((java.util.Date) parameterObj).getTime()));
            } else if (parameterObj instanceof BigInteger) {
                setString(parameterIndex, parameterObj.toString());
            } else {
                setSerializableObject(parameterIndex, parameterObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want more detail, see "com.mysql.jdbc" packages "PreparedStatement" class.

Comment: Awesome, just the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This is interesting. This basically means whatever object reference is sent to `setObject`, it automatically figures out the type and preforms the correct setDouble, setString, setFloat etc.